# Schur's lemma for finite-dimensional unitary representations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, representation-theory

I am reading the book 'Representations of Linear Groups' by Rolf Berndt, and on page 19 they state the following theorem:

'Let $(\pi,\mathbb{C}^n)$ be a unitary matrix representation of a group $G$, i.e. $\pi(g) = A(g)$. Let $M\in GL(n,\mathbb{C}^n)$ be a matrix commuting with all $A(g)$. Then $M$ is a scalar multiple of the unit matrix.'

So far, this is easy to understand. But in the proof they give the argument, that if $a_{i,j} = a_{j,i} = 0$ for all such matrices $A(g)$, then the representation is reducible. I do not see how this holds, there must be some argument why all $A(g)$ then share an invariant subspace, but I fail to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the sound of it, you are happy that $\tilde a_{i,j}=\tilde a_{j,i}=0$ when the diagonal elements are different. What this means is that $\tilde A(g)$ is a block-diagonal matrix, and the same blocks for all $g\in G$. Thus there is either one block, so it's a scalar matrix, or the representation can be written as a direct sum. The invariant subspaces are the eigenspaces of $D$.

Comment: Why does that mean that $\tilde{A(g)}$ is block diagonal? Can't I have something like ((a,0,c),(0,c,d),(e,f,g))?

Comment: In your example, if the first and second elements are different, then sure, the $(1,2)$ and $(2,1)$ entries must be zero. Which one is the $(3,3)$ entry equal to? At least one of $e$ and $f$ is zero as well.

Comment: Oh I see, I made a mistake here, of course the third entry must have some relation to the first ones too... Thank you!